# Styling buttons - <a> vs <input>

Tags: css, forms

For buttons, I now mostly see people using `<a>` for styling buttons. What's the advantage of not using form elements, like the old `<input type="submit">` or `<input type="button">`?

Comment: <input type="submit"/> belongs to form, there are not meant to be hyperlinks . <a> are freed of browsers/OS specfitie to form elements.

Comment: anchors are indexed by bots

Comment: @Shaddow , thats a good one to tell people . do it right !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling a Button: Use Anchor or Input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510122/styling-a-button-use-anchor-or-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic markup.

If the button is to submit a form, then the `<input type="submit">` makes sense.
Otherwise, if it is a link the `<a>` best describes the structure of the element.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor tag is easy to deal with (ie: hover supported in every browsers without digging into doctypes for IE). When a "button-like" is part of a design, it is sometimes easier to format a link than work around buttons default style and behavior.

Also, like Schleis mentionned, semantic is really important. If you think that a link better describe the element, use a `<a>` tag. Whenever it's acting like a button, use `<input>` or `<button>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine this is so much advantage vs. disadvantage so much as semantics. `<input type="submit">` should be used if you're, you know, submitting something. If you have a button that's taking you from place to place on the site, it's an anchor by nature and should be an `<a>`, most likely with the href attribute on it.